# Serving a single JPEG using ffserver

Tags: ffmpeg, jpeg, ffserver

I have a setup where a local application writes a sequence of JPEG images into a FIFO (Unix named pipe on Linux). On the other end I have `ffmpeg` picking up the sequence and passing it into an instance of `ffserver`:

```
% ffmpeg -i fifo.mjpeg http://127.0.0.1:8090/feed.ffm
```

The configuration for `ffserver` looks like this:

```
HTTPPort 8090
HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 20
MaxClients 10
MaxBandwidth 1000

<Feed feed.ffm>
  File /tmp/feed.ffm
  FileMaxSize 200k

  ACL allow 127.0.0.1
</Feed>

<Stream stream.mpjpeg>
  Format mpjpeg
  Feed feed.ffm

  VideoSize 960x600
  VideoFrameRate 2
  VideoIntraOnly
  Strict -1

  NoAudio
  NoDefaults
</Stream>
```

This works fine, I can point my web browser to `http://127.0.0.1:8090/stream.mpjpeg` and see the video.

Now I want to add a way to download a single JPEG (I think of it as  snapshot of the video). I added the following to the `ffserver` configuration:

```
<Stream image.jpg>
  Format singlejpeg
  Feed feed.ffm

  VideoSize 960x600
  VideoFrameRate 2
  VideoIntraOnly
  Strict -1

  NoAudio
  NoDefaults
</Stream>
```

That only sort of works. Sure, if I point my browser to `http://127.0.0.1:8090/image.jpg` I do so a still picture from the video, *but the browser never stops loading!*

Indeed, if I run `wget http://127.0.0.1:8090/image.jpg` I see that the MIME type is good (`image/jpeg`), but there seems to be no end to the image.

Am I missing something in my configuration that makes `ffserver` sending more than a single image?

I should add I've tried this setup on both 2.8.6 (Debian Jessie, package comes from jessie-backports) and 3.0 (Arch Linux), with the same result in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You know, I am in searching to find out an answer to the question. I found only the way to do this using the `mjpg-streamer`:

```
mjpg_streamer -i 'input_uvc.so -f 15 -r 640x480' -o 'output_http.so'
```

gives you to download the snapshots via `http://localhost:8080/?action=snapshot`. But I could to do this using the ffmpeg...

**EDIT:**

It looks like I figured out how to make the "snapshotable" ffserver. Here is my configuration:

```
HTTPPort 8090
HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 20
MaxClients 10
MaxBandwidth 100000

<Feed feed.ffm>
  File /tmp/feed.ffm
  FileMaxSize 200k

  ACL allow 127.0.0.1
</Feed>

<Stream image.jpg>
  Feed feed.ffm
  Format jpeg

  VideoSize 800x600
  VideoFrameRate 30
  Preroll 5
  VideoIntraOnly
  Strict -1

  NoAudio
  NoDefaults
</Stream>
```

**EDIT:**

Unfortunately this method gives a strange hangs sometimes...